# NUCLEO F429ZI board - Ethernet over usb - zperf example communication issue

Tags: usb, stm32f4, nucleo, zephyr-rtos

I need help running the [zerpf](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/tree/main/samples/net/zperf) example with USB over ethernet for the STM32 NUCLEO F429ZI board. I could run the example with an ethernet port and ping the connection using iperf-2.0.5b-win32.

However, when I have configured the proj.conf file by adding these lines for setting Ethernet over USB.

```
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_STACK=y 
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_NETWORK_ECM=n
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_NETWORK=y
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_NETWORK_RNDIS=y
CONFIG_NET_IPV6=n #Disabled this flag else mcu reboot again and again when the command is sent)
```

These configuration settings are also described here: [sample.net.zperf.netusb_rndis](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/main/samples/net/zperf/sample.yaml) After flashing the code, an RNDIS network is discovered via a USB connection, and I can manually set the network's IP. However, when I run iperf-2.0.5b-win32 in server mode on my Windows 11 and send `zperf tcp upload 192.0.2.2 5001 10 1K 1M` on the board, I get the error.

**TCP upload failed (-116)**

The connection is not established for TCP. Also, I am getting an error for UDP upload failed (-115). Can anyone help me understand what the problem might be?

Comment: The subject does not reflect the content